# Points on curve where tangent are equally inclined

Tags: geometry, derivatives

What are the points on the curve $ x^{3/2} + y^{3/2} = a^{3/2} $ where the tangents are equally inclined to the axes?

Comment: What have you done, tried, achieved... in this question?

Comment: Is this $a^{3/2}$ or $a^3 / 2$? I assumed it was the former, because you wrote "a^3{/2}", and the problem has thus far referred to $3/2$.

Comment: @GeorgeV.Williams - sorry fixed now

Comment: till now i have tried to find the slope of the curve and equated to +-1

Comment: I don't understand the question at all. Why tangents, in plural? The curve has only one tangent at each point! And inclined equally to what? And to what axis?

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen - edited for grammer change!

Comment: Is the question to find when the derivative of the function is $1$ or $-1$?

Answer (score 1):

$$x^{3/2}+y^{3/2}=\frac{a^3}{2}\Longrightarrow \frac{3}{2}\left(x^{1/2}\,dx+ y^{1/2}\,dy\right)=0\Longrightarrow$$

$$y'=-\sqrt\frac{x}{y}\Longrightarrow \,\text{two points}(x_1,y_1)\,,\,(x_2,y_2)\,\,\text{fulfill the condition}\Longleftrightarrow \frac{x_1}{x_2}=\frac{y_1}{y_2}$$

-- I'll leave it to you to check what happens when $\,x=0\,\,\vee\,\,\,y=0\,$ --

Since it must be that $\,x,y\geq 0\,$ (why?) , and also

$$y=\sqrt[3]{\left(\frac{a^3}{2}-x^{3/2}\right)^2}$$  we get

$$\frac{x_1}{x_2}=\frac{y_1}{y_2}=\left(\frac{\frac{a^3}{2}-x_1^{3/2}}{\frac{a^3}{2}-x_2^{3/2}}\right)^{2/3}\stackrel{\text{after a little algebra}}\Longleftrightarrow x_1^{3/2}=x_2^{3/2}$$

so...

Comment: The above answer is made with the *original post* where it was written $\,a^3/2\,$ and not the edited one of $\,a^{3/2}\,$ . Nevertheless, following the general lines of the above one can reach the answer to the new question.